# Neutrino's relativistic four-momentum

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, neutrinos

In an exercise I have to solve there is an apparently contradiction that I can't figure out.
In a pion decay, where a muon and a neutrino are produced, conservation of quadric-momentum states:
\begin{equation}
 P_\pi=P_\mu+P_\nu
\end{equation}
which holds for both lab frame and the centre-of-mass frame.

In the centre-of-mass frame I found
\begin{equation}
 \rvert {\textbf p'}_\nu\lvert=\frac{m_\pi^2-m_\mu^2}{2m_\pi}
\end{equation}
while, in the lab frame I come out with this
\begin{equation}
 \rvert {\textbf p}_\nu\lvert=\frac{m_\pi^2-m_\mu^2}{2m_\pi\gamma}
\end{equation}
with an extra $\gamma$ factor due to the relativistic energy of the pion.

My question is: isn't the modulus of a vector Lorentz-invariant?

Comment: What you have written is the modulus of a 3-vector which is not invariant under a change of frame.